# Cross-domain AJAX request to Django server

Tags: javascript, django, jquery, cross-domain

I'm trying to get data from Django server using jQuery.

Here is code I'm using: [myCode](http://jsfiddle.net/aABA3/)

```
    $(function(){
    function callback(res){
        console.log(res);
    }
    $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.chesno.org/ajax/dispatcher/",
            data: {
                "data": "{'cmd':'get_party_list'}"
            },
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: callback,
            complete: callback,
            crossDomain: true,
            async: false
        });
    })​
```

The interesting thing is that I'm able to reach data through browser or fiddler ([link](http://www.chesno.org/ajax/dispatcher/?data=%7B%27cmd%27%3a%27get_party_list%27%7D)).
Please give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong. The important part is that I don't have access to the server, I just can communicate with developers of the site and they don't know yet where the problem is.

Comment: You're going to want to read up on CORS.  Unless the site developers have explictly allowed your domain to query it's content, you won't be able to grab the data this way.  You'll either need to use a jsonp request or a script on your back end to grab the content.  I typically employ the 2nd

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please give me an example on how to use jsonp in my situation?

Comment: You'll need to contact the developers and have the wrap their output in a jsonp callback.  This site should help you understand jsonp a bit better:  http://json-p.org/.  I usually use my 2nd option preceisely because the other site needs to be involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service provider needs to employ [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) and have it's resources respond with a [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header that matches your origin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the communicating with service developers takes a little time, you know, so do you know another way to accomplish my goal without it and without using backend on my side?